# How to change the scrollbar's position on Scrollpane

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

Everyone.

I don't know how to change the scrollbar's position on Scrollpane  in my code.

The current situation, the scrollbar's position is the Left, but I'd like to change the position rignt.

Could you give me any advices.

Thanks.

Comment: I guess you made a typo. The current must be right. Isn't it ?

Comment: Hi,ItachiUchida.
unfortunately, i don't think i made a typo.

the scroll bar is located in the far left most.
SO, i'd like to show in the far right most...

Comment: can you add an image?